# How to change the K matrix as well as the distortion coefficients to simulate the barrel distortion in python with the help of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, intrinsics, distortion

I have the intrensic paramaters of my camera, as well as the distortion coefficents, and I know how to calculate out the barrel distortion. - Mainly from this blogpost:

[Barrel distortion calculation](https://hackaday.io/project/12384-autofan-automated-control-of-air-flow/log/41862-correcting-for-lens-distortions)

However, now I wish to add the barrel distortion like it would be done by the camera itself.

The code for correcting the barrel distortion is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Define camera matrix K
K = np.array([[1.051e+03,0,0],
             [0, 1.0845e+03,0],
             [964.4480,544.2625,1.]])
#Matrix was written in matlab style, hence it has to be transposed ... 
K = K.transpose()



# Define distortion coefficients d
d = np.array([0.0719,-0.0833,0.0013,-6.1840e-04,0])
# Read an example image and acquire its size

img = cv2.imread("grid.png")
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Generate new camera matrix from parameters
newcameramatrix, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(K, d, (w,h), 0)

# Generate look-up tables for remapping the camera image
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, d, None, newcameramatrix, (w, h), 5)

# Remap the original image to a new image
newimg = cv2.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Display old and new image
fig, (oldimg_ax, newimg_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
oldimg_ax.imshow(img)
oldimg_ax.set_title('Original image')
newimg_ax.imshow(newimg)
newimg_ax.set_title('Unwarped image')
plt.show()
```

I tried to simualte the barrel distortion by using the inverse of th K-Matrix, or the transposed K-matrix, as well as multiplicating the d-vector with -1.

I transposed it via:

```
K = K.transpose()
```

or inverted it via:

```
K = np.linalg.inv(K)
```

Howver, this gave me only a black image. If I do not inverted / transpose it all I just get a negative radial resolution, however I need a positive radial distortion

Comment: Take a look to the opencv [fisheye::distortPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#ga75d8877a98e38d0b29b6892c5f8d7765) function, it does more less what you want to do. Also, you can take a look to the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L255) which is not a big function and can be easily implemented/studied and maybe modified to your liking. Sadly it is only in c++ and not Python, but it is just math, I am sure you can translate it to python. The important part is from line 289-307

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take a look at it